# A person capable of knowing anything and everything

Tags: scripture, brahman, terminology, knowledge

In sanathan dharma, Sarvajna stands for a person who realizes that everything is Brahman.

So, Sarvajna is not the person I'm asking for.

I know that saguna brahman satisfies the property mentioned in the title.

But is there another concept in the scriptures that says that a person capable of knowing anything exists?

Comment: "all possible knowledge" is an ill-defined concept, like "set of all sets" @hanugm

Comment: Adisankara is said to have ascended the sarvanjnya सर्वज्ञ peetha - seat of all knowledge @hanugm

Comment: @SK Do you mean the head of Sarvajna peeta knows any branch of knowledge...

Comment: What do you mean by 'anything'? To paraphrase Vivekananda, a realized soul who knows Brahman, knows what 'clay' is. It does not mean that he knows every form that clay has taken. The human brain is part of the sensual universe with its physical limitations. You can't put 5 litres in a 1 litre bottle. There is a material limit.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Yeah, exactly, I want the nomenclature and details of persons who know every form of clay also...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Anything here is any possible form of clay as per analogy...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda so,  Did Vemana Krishna, Rama, etc. also has such limitation? I mean saguna Brahman as human...

Comment: Your question is very imprecise and poorly stated. If you wanted to ask if there is any reference to an omniscient person in the vedic literature, to that I don't know the answer. However, usually the uphanishades don't pertain to the intellectual knowledge, when they state "that one knows all", it pouts to knowledge beyond intellect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is concept in the Hindu Scriptures that say that a person capable of knowing everything. I will add quotes from Scriptures in sequence to explain properly.

> What is that, O Bhagavan **which being known, all this becomes known**?
> (Mundaka Upanishad 1.1.3)
>
> I shall now declare unto you in full this knowledge both phenomenal
> and noumenal, by knowing which there shall remain nothing further to
> be known.(Gita 7.2)
>
> When an inquisitive person comes to understand this knowledge, he has
> nothing further to know. After all, one who has drunk the most
> palatable nectar cannot remain thirsty.(Bhagavata 11.29.32)
>
> To the Brahmana who has known the Self, all the Vedas are of as much
> use as is a reservoir of water in a place where there is a flood.(Gita
> 2.46)
>
> He, verily, is the **immortal Self. Knowing him, one knows all
> things**.(Katha Upanishad 2.1.3)
>
> That which is the subtlest of all is the Self of all this. It is the
> Truth. It is the Self. That thou art, O Śvetaketu.(Chandogya Upanishad
> 6.8.7)
>
> This is my Soul in the innermost heart, greater than the earth,
> greater than the aerial space, greater than these worlds. This Soul,
> this Self of mine is that Brahman.(Chandogya Upanishad 3.14.3-4)
>
> **He who knows the Supreme Brahman verily becomes Brahman**. In his family
> no one is born ignorant of Brahman. He overcomes grief; he overcomes
> evil; free from the fetters of the heart, he becomes immortal.
> (Mundaka Upanishad 3.2.9)
>
> And when he becomes a god, as it were, or a king, as it were, or
> thinks, ‘**This universe is myself, who am all,’ that is his highest
> state.**(Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 4.3.20)